# Putting the verb in the beginning of the sentence to emphasize it

Tags: fronting

> **Gone** *are* the hardware concerns of A, yet with B, you control the application.

Is it that kind of a construction when to emphasize a term you put it in the beginning of the sentence and put the verb after it?

So the normal sentence would look:

> The hardware concerns of A *are* **gone**, yet, with B, you control the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an old-fashioned literary use which you are unlikely to encounter in contemporary written English, much less conversation. It does emphasize the *gone*; but this is not because it is first but because it is so oddly placed.

Other things being equal, the strongest position in any clause is the ***final*** one, not the first, because in the simplest sentences this is where "new" information normally falls.

Comment: It is from the oficial Google documentation, by the way.

Comment: @Graduate There's a lot of horrible writing on that page.

Comment: "Gone are the days, when my heart was young and gay."

Comment: @TomAu We're probably the last generation to have learned that song ... As I said, a literary use.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, you will find this construction very often in chess literature:

```
Better is 21. ... e5 22. Nc4 Qa3 23. Rb5 e6 24. Kxe6 Qa2+!
More to the point is b5.
```

Perhaps the construction appears in other technical literature as well?