# Broad knowledge, is what my friends are proud of me

Tags: grammar

I have two sentences:

> Broad knowledge, is what my friends proud of me.
>   Never stop asking question, is what my advisor values me.

*Many* people say that they are wrong in grammar, but I can't see where these wrongs are. Can you point them out? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence needs a verb inside the subordinate clause, like this:

> Broad knowledge is what **makes** my friends proud of me.

The second sentence is wrong for a couple reasons. First, **never stop asking questions** is intended to be a clause that serves as the direct object of **values**. To play that role, it needs a subordinating conjunction like **that** and a subject of its own. Second, **me** sounds like the direct object of **values**, clashing with the subordinate clause, which also sounds like it's trying to play that role. To make **me** into an indirect object, you need to precede it with a preposition.

Here are a couple ways to fix it:

> **That I** never stop asking questions is what my advisor values **about** me.
>
> My advisor values me **because** I never stop asking questions.

You have to say **questions** rather than **question** because you are asking many questions, not just one. (I don't think your advisor would value you so much if you kept asking just one question over and over again.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, I would like to put the phrase "Never stop asking questions" in the beginning of the sentence. I would like to make something from "She is lovely" to "Lovely, she is". Does this sound natural?

Comment: @Ooker "Lovely, she is" is grammatical and clear. It has unusual but still familiar word ordering, suitable for strong emphasis and poetry. You can get a feeling for that sort of thing by reading poetry, especially 19th-century poetry.

Comment: @Ooker Putting "Never stop asking questions" at the beginning of the sentence is harder. I have to think about it. One way is to put it in quotation marks: "'Never stop asking questions' is the principle that makes my advisor value me." But that sounds clumsy to me. I'll post another comment if I get a better idea.

Comment: @Ooker By the way, the title of your message is "Broad knowledge, is what my friends are proud of me" (with the verb **are** in the subordinate clause). You could make that correct like this: "Broad knowledge is **why** my friends are proud of me."

Comment: @Ooker OK, here are a couple ideas, maybe not fully satisfactory. You could break it into two sentences: "I never stop asking questions. That's why my advisor values me." Or you could say this: "My never stopping asking questions is why my advisor values me." Neither of these starts with the word "Never" because the clause needs a subject. There probably is a way to start the sentence with "Never stop asking questions", but I suspect it will come out very awkward-sounding even if grammatically correct.

Comment: I find this question is similar: [Putting the verb in the beginning of the sentence to emphasize it](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7674/putting-the-verb-in-the-beginning-of-the-sentence-to-emphasize-it). I decide to put all those clauses to then end of the sentences. Thank you so much for taking your time and effort to help.